# Netsuite scheduled script creates and applies customerpayment to invoice, but after save different invoice is applied

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

My scheduled script is creating `customerpayment` objects in the loop and applies it to the selected invoices.

Expected: After customerpayment record save the customerpayment should have the exact invoices applied.

The problem: After customerpayment record save, I open the customerpayment and different invoices are applied.

The code that creates the customerpayment:

```
if (paydata != null) {
    paymentfee = paydata.paymentFee;
    for (var y = 0; y < paydata.payments.length; y++) {
            var paymentrec = null;
            log.debug('entity', paydata.payments[y].customerRef);
            paymentrec = record.create({
                    type: 'customerpayment',
                    defaultValues: {
                            'entity': paydata.payments[y].customerRef
                    }
            });
            paymentrec.setValue({
                    fieldId: 'subsidiary',
                    value: paydata.subsidiaryId
            });


            // when we create the payment with account - it's automatically deposited
            paymentrec.setValue({
                fieldId: 'account',
                value: paydata.account
            });

            // adding support for custom form functionality
            if (paydata.payments[y].customform) {
                paymentrec.setValue({
                    fieldId: 'customform',
                    value: paydata.payments[y].customform
                });
                log.debug('Custom form applied', paydata.payments[y].customform);
            }

            paymentrec.setValue({
                    fieldId: 'memo',
                    value: paydata.payments[y].note
            });
            paymentrec.setValue({
                    fieldId: 'payment',
                    value: paydata.payments[y].paymentAmount
            });

            // // debugging the auto-application on the invoices
            // paymentrec.setValue({
            //     fieldId: 'autoapply',
            //     value: false
            // })

            paymentrec.setValue({
                    fieldId: 'custbody_peakflo_payref',
                    value: paydata.peakfloPaymentRef
            });
            paymentrec.setValue({
                    fieldId: 'custbody_peakflo_payacct',
                    value: paydata.account
            });
            paymentrec.setValue({
                    fieldId: 'custbody_peakflo_payfee',
                    value: paydata.paymentFee
            });
            paymentrec.setText({
                    fieldId: 'currency',
                    value: paydata.currency
            });

            for (var z = 0; z < paydata.payments[y].invoiceLines.length; z++) {
                    if (paydata.payments[y].invoiceLines[z].NetSuiteInvoiceInternalId != '' && paydata.payments[y].invoiceLines[z].NetSuiteInvoiceInternalId != null) {
                            log.debug('count', paymentrec.getLineCount({
                                    sublistId: 'apply'
                            }));

                            for (var al = 0; al < paymentrec.getLineCount({sublistId: 'apply'}); al++) {
                                    log.debug('comparison data', JSON.stringify(
                                        {
                                            recordInternalId: paymentrec.getSublistValue({
                                                sublistId: 'apply',
                                                fieldId: 'internalid',
                                                line: al
                                            }),
                                            payloadInvoiceId: paydata.payments[y].invoiceLines[z].NetSuiteInvoiceInternalId,
                                            isEqual: paymentrec.getSublistValue({
                                                sublistId: 'apply',
                                                fieldId: 'internalid',
                                                line: al
                                            }) == paydata.payments[y].invoiceLines[z].NetSuiteInvoiceInternalId
                                        }));

                                if (paymentrec.getSublistValue({
                                            sublistId: 'apply',
                                            fieldId: 'internalid',
                                            line: al
                                    }) == paydata.payments[y].invoiceLines[z].NetSuiteInvoiceInternalId) {
                                            paymentrec.setSublistValue({
                                                    sublistId: 'apply',
                                                    fieldId: 'apply',
                                                    line: al,
                                                    value: true
                                            });
                                            paymentrec.setSublistValue({
                                                    sublistId: 'apply',
                                                    fieldId: 'amount',
                                                    line: al,
                                                    value: paydata.payments[y].invoiceLines[z].PaymentAmount
                                            });
                                            var inv_qm = record.create({type: 'customrecord_peakflo_history_qm'});
                                            inv_qm.setValue({fieldId: 'custrecord_pf_hqm_dg_pri', value: '2'});
                                            inv_qm.setValue({
                                                    fieldId: 'custrecord_pf_hqm_recsub',
                                                    value: paymentrec.getValue({fieldId: 'subsidiary'})
                                            });
                                            inv_qm.setValue({
                                                    fieldId: 'custrecord_pf_hqm_rectype',
                                                    value: 'transaction'
                                            });
                                            inv_qm.setValue({
                                                    fieldId: 'custrecord_pf_hqm_recid',
                                                    value: paydata.payments[y].invoiceLines[z].NetSuiteInvoiceInternalId
                                            });
                                            var inv_qmid = inv_qm.save();
                                            log.debug('payment amt', paydata.payments[y].invoiceLines[z].PaymentAmount);
                                            log.debug('HQM created id', inv_qmid);

                                    }
                                    log.debug('Selected', paymentrec.getSublistValue({
                                        sublistId: 'apply',
                                        fieldId: 'apply',
                                        line: al
                                    }));
                            }
                    }
            }
            var paymentrecid = paymentrec.save({
                    ignoreMandatoryFields: true,
                    enableSourcing: true
            });
            record.submitFields({
                    type:'customrecord_peakflo_qm',
                    id:pfp_s_res[x].id,
                    values:{
                            custrecord_pf_processed:true
                    }
            });
            log.debug('payment id', paymentrecid);
            if (paymentrecid) {
                    paymentref.push(paymentrecid);
            }
    }
}
```

According to the logs, the customerpayment should have invoice 9236675 applied.
[image: Logs of customerpayment creation]

However, when I open the customerpayment, it shows that invoice 9236677 is applied.
[image: Customerpayment with wrong invoice applied]

I can reproduce it in client instance, but it seem to work correctly in my own instance. What can be the reason behind this?

#### UPDATE 06 AUG

I modified my script as was proposed in the comments, but I am still facing the same issues:

```
var paymentrec = record.create({
    type: 'customerpayment',
    defaultValues: {
            'entity': paymentData.customerRef
    }
});
paymentrec.setValue({
    fieldId: 'subsidiary',
    value: paydata.subsidiaryId
});

// when we create the payment with account - it's automatically deposited
paymentrec.setValue({
    fieldId: 'account',
    value: paydata.account
});

// adding support for custom form functionality
if (paymentData.customform) {
    paymentrec.setValue({
        fieldId: 'customform',
        value: paymentData.customform
    });
    log.debug('Custom form applied', paymentData.customform);
}

paymentrec.setValue({
        fieldId: 'memo',
        value: paymentData.note
});
paymentrec.setValue({
        fieldId: 'payment',
        value: paymentData.paymentAmount
});

paymentrec.setValue({
        fieldId: 'custbody_peakflo_payref',
        value: paydata.peakfloPaymentRef
});
paymentrec.setValue({
        fieldId: 'custbody_peakflo_payacct',
        value: paydata.account
});
paymentrec.setValue({
        fieldId: 'custbody_peakflo_payfee',
        value: paydata.paymentFee
});
paymentrec.setText({
        fieldId: 'currency',
        value: paydata.currency
});

var anyApplied = false;

// iterate through paymentrec which has all outstanding invoices as lines
peakflo.iter(paymentrec, 'apply', function(al, getV, setV) { // make the payment apply lines the outer loop so can also turn off application if a line is not matched
    var didFind = false;

    // iterate through all input payment data incoie lines 
    paymentData.invoiceLines.forEach(function(invLine, z) {
        if (!invLine.NetSuiteInvoiceInternalId || getV('doc') != invLine.NetSuiteInvoiceInternalId) return;


        didFind = true;
        anyApplied = true;

        setV('apply', true);
        setV('amount', invLine.PaymentAmount);

        log.debug('payment amt', 
            JSON.stringify(
                {
                    payloadAmount: invLine.PaymentAmount, 
                    recordLineAmount: paymentrec.getSublistValue({
                        sublistId: 'apply',
                        fieldId: 'amount',
                        line: al
                        })
                }
            )
        );

        log.debug('Selected', paymentrec.getSublistValue({
            sublistId: 'apply',
            fieldId: 'apply',
            line: al
        }));
    });

    // if the invoice was not found in the payload we set applied to false
    if (!didFind) setV('apply', false);

});

// if any of the invoices were applied 
if (anyApplied) {

    // saving the payment record
    var paymentrecid = paymentrec.save({
        ignoreMandatoryFields: true,
        enableSourcing: false //the default is false. true can cause interesting behaviour. You have already initialized it to the customer defaults so further sourcing shouldn't be needed
    });
    record.submitFields({
        type: 'customrecord_peakflo_qm',
        id: pfp_s_res[x].id,
        values: {
            custrecord_pf_processed: true
        }
    });
    log.debug('payment id', paymentrecid);
    if (paymentrecid) {
        paymentref.push(paymentrecid);
    }
} else {
    log.error({
        title: 'no open invoice found',
        details: JSON.stringify(pd)
    });
}
});
```

Logs:
[image: Logs of the updated code]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe things have changed but in the past when I've tried to manually manage the payments the invoice internal id goes to the sublist field `doc`, not `internalid`. Yes this is strangely inconsistent.

If you are trying to pay a single invoice then you should intialize the customer payment from the invoice and not the customer. This means your payment will automatically be applied to the correct invoice:

```js
var paymentrec = record.transform({
    fromType:'invoice',
    fromId: paydata.payments[y].invoiceLines[z].NetSuiteInvoiceInternalId,
    toType:'customerpayment',
});
```

In an effort to see where your code might have been going wrong I did a quick re-write to use `doc` and to for a couple of other commented reasons. Try the code below:

```js
if (paydata) {
    paymentfee = paydata.paymentFee;
    paydata.payments.forEach(function(pd, y) {
        log.debug('entity', pd.customerRef);
        var paymentrec = record.create({
            type: 'customerpayment',
            defaultValues: {
                'entity': pd.customerRef
            }
        });
        paymentrec.setValue({
            fieldId: 'subsidiary',
            value: paydata.subsidiaryId
        });


        // when we create the payment with account - it's automatically deposited
        paymentrec.setValue({
            fieldId: 'account',
            value: paydata.account
        });

        // adding support for custom form functionality
        if (pd.customform) {
            paymentrec.setValue({
                fieldId: 'customform',
                value: pd.customform
            });
            log.debug('Custom form applied', pd.customform);
        }

        paymentrec.setValue({
            fieldId: 'memo',
            value: pd.note
        });
        paymentrec.setValue({
            fieldId: 'payment',
            value: pd.paymentAmount
        });

        // // debugging the auto-application on the invoices
        // paymentrec.setValue({
        //     fieldId: 'autoapply',
        //     value: false
        // })

        paymentrec.setValue({
            fieldId: 'custbody_peakflo_payref',
            value: paydata.peakfloPaymentRef
        });
        paymentrec.setValue({
            fieldId: 'custbody_peakflo_payacct',
            value: paydata.account
        });
        paymentrec.setValue({
            fieldId: 'custbody_peakflo_payfee',
            value: paydata.paymentFee
        });
        paymentrec.setText({
            fieldId: 'currency',
            value: paydata.currency
        });

        var anyApplied = false;

        iter(paymentrec, 'apply', function(al, getV, setV) { // make the payment apply lines the outer loop so can also turn off application if a line is not matched
            var didFind = false;

            pd.invoiceLines.forEach(function(invLine, z) {
                if (!invLine.NetSuiteInvoiceInternalId || getV('doc') != invLine.NetSuiteInvoiceInternalId) return;


                didFind = true;
                anyApplied = true;

                setV('apply', true);
                setV('amount', invLine.PaymentAmount);

                var inv_qm = record.create({
                    type: 'customrecord_peakflo_history_qm'
                });
                inv_qm.setValue({
                    fieldId: 'custrecord_pf_hqm_dg_pri',
                    value: '2'
                });
                inv_qm.setValue({
                    fieldId: 'custrecord_pf_hqm_recsub',
                    value: paymentrec.getValue({
                        fieldId: 'subsidiary'
                    })
                });
                inv_qm.setValue({
                    fieldId: 'custrecord_pf_hqm_rectype',
                    value: 'transaction'
                });
                inv_qm.setValue({
                    fieldId: 'custrecord_pf_hqm_recid',
                    value: invLine.NetSuiteInvoiceInternalId
                });
                var inv_qmid = inv_qm.save();
                log.debug('payment amt', invLine.PaymentAmount);
                log.debug('HQM created id', inv_qmid);


                log.debug('Selected', paymentrec.getSublistValue({
                    sublistId: 'apply',
                    fieldId: 'apply',
                    line: al
                }));
            });
            if (!didFind) setV('apply', false);

        });

        if (anyApplied) {

            var paymentrecid = paymentrec.save({
                ignoreMandatoryFields: true,
                enableSourcing: false //the default is false. true can cause interesting behaviour. You have already initialized it to the customer defaults so further sourcing shouldn't be needed
            });
            record.submitFields({
                type: 'customrecord_peakflo_qm',
                id: pfp_s_res[x].id,
                values: {
                    custrecord_pf_processed: true
                }
            });
            log.debug('payment id', paymentrecid);
            if (paymentrecid) {
                paymentref.push(paymentrecid);
            }
        } else {
            log.error({
                title: 'no open invoice found',
                details: JSON.stringify(pd)
            });
        }
    });

    function iter(rec, listName, cb) {
        var lim = rec.getLineCount({
            sublistId: listName
        });
        var i = 0;
        var getV = function(fld) {
            return rec.getSublistValue({
                sublistId: listName,
                fieldId: fld,
                line: i
            });
        };
        var setV = function(fld, val) {
            return rec.setSublistValue({
                sublistId: listName,
                fieldId: fld,
                line: i,
                value: val
            });
        };
        for (; i < lim; i++) {
            cb(i, getV, setV);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: >when I've tried to manually manage the payments the invoice internal id goes to the sublist field doc, not internalid. Yes this is strangely inconsistent.
I am logging the values of internalid field in the `comparison data` log. Do you mean that read is from field and write should be in another field?

Also, In my use case there can be multiple invoices within one payment. Is there a reliable solution for this case as well?

Comment: see update with a re-write of your code

Comment: Thanks for the update, I've tried this approach and the payload `[{"NetSuiteInvoiceInternalId":"9680747","PaymentAmount":42.8},{"NetSuiteInvoiceInternalId":"9679754","PaymentAmount":2436.8}]`
resulted in application of 42.80 to invoice 9680747 and 42.80 to invoice 9679754.
 There were only 2 outstanding invoices for this customer. I don't follow how is this possible. It should apply 2436.8 to invoice 9679754.
I checked the logs and the script tried to apply correct amounts.

Comment: I also checked the logs and the script tried to apply correct amounts: https://imgur.com/nIhG09M

Comment: I have attached the latest script and a screenshot to the original post. The issue still persists